# Adding vertical scrollability to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jpanel

Ok so I have a class named AppMain that extends JFrame and a JPanel (called panel) where I add various JSwing components (buttons, labels, separators) that the user can press for various actions. One such action is to (on run-time) add a whole JPanel with various JSpinners and TextAreas. Details of that are in a class called PlayerCharacter that extends JPanel. When you create many panels you run out of vertical space and no scrollbar is created automatically. My problem is how to add the scrollbar. I tried making a ScrollPane in which I put a second panel.

Code looks a bit like this:

```
public class AppMain extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppMain();
}

private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private static JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPanel);
JButton addPlayerButton = new JButton("Add player");

AppMain() {
    super("window name");
    setSize(1200, 750);
    setLocation(250, 50);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);
    addPlayerButton.setBounds(5, 5, 150, 40);
    contentPanel.setBounds(5, 10, 1100, 750);
    scrollPane.setBounds(5, 10, 1100, 750);
    panel.add(addPlayerButton);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    interfaceControls();
}

public void interfaceControls() {
    addPlayerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    JLabel tmpLabel = new JLabel("text " + i);
                    tmpLabel.setBounds(5, (100 + (100 * i)), 100, 100);
                    contentPanel.add(tmpLabel);
                    contentPanel.revalidate();
                    contentPanel.repaint();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

}
}
```

EDIT: and for those wondering the code that works:

```
public class AppMain extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppMain();
}

private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
JButton addPlayerButton = new JButton("Add player");



AppMain() {
    super("window name");
    setSize(1200, 750);
    setLocation(250, 50);
    JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(contentPanel);

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(addPlayerButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(scrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    interfaceControls();
}

public void interfaceControls() {
    addPlayerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    JButton dynamicButton = new JButton("text " + i);
                    contentPanel.add(dynamicButton);
                    contentPanel.revalidate();
                    contentPanel.repaint();
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Best would be to provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't mind sharing the project but I am not sure how safe that is

We NEVER want to see you entire application. That is too much code to look at. Instead we want to see a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which is simplified code that demonstrates the "concept" of what you are trying to do.

A SSCCE should be included with all you question. Rarely will posting 4 lines of code give us the information we need to help solve your problem. Another benefit of a SSCCE is that often you will find the problem while attempting to create the SSCCE because finding a problem in 20 lines of code is easier than debugging 200 lines of code.

```
contentPanel.add(newPlayerCharacter);
panel.validate();
panel.repaint();
```

The normal code should be:

```
contentPanel.add(newPlayerCharacter);
contentPanel.revalidate(); // note the "re"
contentPanel.repaint();
```

If that doesn't help then post a proper SSCCE in the question.

Edit:

Don't use null layouts (and setBounds())!!!

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. I don't know what you actual layout is, so I'll just point you to the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

The scrollbars will appear automatically when the preferred size of the component added to the viewport of the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. The layout manager is responsible for determining the preferred size. Since you are using a null layout the preferred size is (0, 0) so there is no reason to display a scrollbar.

Comment: @RekijanKileren, The code you posted: 1) does not implement my suggestion. 2) is not a SSCCE. We can't execute your code because we don't have access to your "newPlayerCharacter" class. And we don't want access to your class because that class is irrelevant to your question. You question is about adding a component to a panel in a scrollpane. So add a JLabel. `Keep the code simple!!!`. Until you post a proper SSCCE I can't help.

Comment: I edited the original post again. Hopefully this provides a better insight. Thanks so far for sticking with me :)

Comment: @RekijanKileren see edit... Better SSCCE. The problem becomes more apparent.

Comment: Thanks for your patient with me, as you can see I solved the issue based on your comments. I would upvote you too, but I am not allowed yet.